# PHP ssh2_fingerprint() does not match ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa.pub

Tags: php, ssh

I am using the lib ssh2 module with PHP and calling the function ssh2_fingerprint() to get the keys fingerprint. According to all resources on the internet, I can get the fingerprint of a public key by executing:

```
ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa.pub
```

Which outputs something like:

```
2048 d4:41:3b:45:00:49:4e:fc:2c:9d:3a:f7:e6:6e:bf:e7 id_rsa.pub (RSA)
```

However, when I call `ssh2_fingerprint($connection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX)` in PHP with the same public key I get:

```
dddddba52352e5ab95711c10fdd56f43
```

Shouldn't they match? What am I missing?

Comment: Cross posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508258/php-ssh2-fingerprint-does-not-match-ssh-keygen-lf-id-rsa-pub

Comment: Thanks, Evan. Deleted the other post. Still in search of an answer.